# Derivative of $\|X-\alpha Y\|_2$ with respect to $\alpha$.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, operator-theory, convex-analysis, spectral-norm

Let $X$ and $Y$ be operators on a real or complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $f(\alpha) = \|X - \alpha Y\|_2$ where $\alpha$ is real and $\|A\|_2 = \sigma_{\mathsf{max}}(A)$ is the $\ell^2$-induced operator norm. What is $\frac{df}{d\alpha}$?

Even if the function is not differentiable everywhere, $f$ is convex in which case a sub-gradient will suffice.

Also, if it helps we can assume $X=I$ and $Y$ is positive definite but I'd rather see a more general result. Also considering $f^2$ instead of $f$ is also fine if that helps.

**Plots of $f$**: I ran two simple numerical examples which might be enlightening. In the following plot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krgjA.png), $X = I\in M_{50}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Y = Z^\mathsf{T}Z + I$ where $Z_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is normally distributed. As we can see, the plot seems piecewise linear.
[image: plot of f using]

In the next plot [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng2Wq.png), we take $X_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1) - I \in M_{50}(\mathbb{R})$ and $Y_{ij}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Note that neither $X$ nor $Y$ are symmetric. This example looks differentiable and practically quadratic.[image]

Comment: Can you clarify where the inner product comes up? Here $\|X\|_2 = \sigma_{\mathsf{max}}(X)$ is the $\ell^2$-induced operator norm which I don't think arises from an inner product?

Comment: I've deleted my comment and answer. Thomas' comment (which he has since deleted) was spot on. I assumed we were referring here to the Euclidean norm on the space.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the confusion! I've updated the question to clarify which norm I'm using here. If you both thought I meant the Frobenius norm you end up with $f'(\alpha) = \alpha\,\mathsf{tr}\,Y^*Y - \mathsf{Re}\,\mathsf{tr}\,X^*Y$ which makes sense since solving for the optimal $\alpha$ gives the orthogonal projection as we'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's at least a subset of cases here where we can do this. Note that for any norm $\|\cdot\|$,
$$\|W\| = \sup_{\|Z\|_* \leq 1} \langle W, Z \rangle$$
where $\|\cdot\|_*$ is the dual norm. For the case of the matrix spectral norm, the dual norm is the nuclear norm (the sum of the singular values). Any maximizing value of $Z$ above is a subgradient of the norm at that point. That is, let $Z^*$ be any point satisfying
$$\|Z\|_* = 1, \quad \langle W, Z \rangle = \|W\|.$$
 then
$$\|W + \delta W\| \geq \langle W + \delta W, Z^* \rangle = \langle W, Z^* \rangle + \langle \delta W, Z^* \rangle = \|W\| + \langle Z^*, \delta W \rangle$$
so $Z^* \in \partial \|W\|$. For the matrix spectral norm, valid values of $Z^*$ are readily obtained: if $W=U\Sigma V = \sum_i \sigma_i u_i v_i^H$ is the SVD of $W$, then
$$\partial \|W\|_2 = \mathop{\textrm{Conv}}\{u_iv_i^H\,|\,\sigma_i=1\}.$$

Now in the case where $W=X-\alpha Y$ and $\delta W=-\alpha Y$, then, we have
$$\|X-(\alpha+\delta \alpha)Y\| \geq \|X-\alpha Y\| + \langle Z^*, -\delta \alpha Y\rangle = \|X-\alpha Y\| - \delta\alpha \langle Z^*, Y \rangle$$
So $-\langle Z^*, Y \rangle \in \partial f(\alpha)$. For the matrix spectral norm, the subgradient can be obtained using the above SVD approach on $X-\alpha Y$ to obtain values of $Z^*$. So we have
$$\partial f(\alpha) \subseteq \mathop{\textrm{Conv}}\{-\Re{v_i^TZu_i}\,|\,Z\in\partial \|X-\alpha Y\|_2\}.$$

Comment: Are you sure that $\partial \|W\|_2$ is defined as the convex hull for $\sigma_i=1$? Shouldn't it involve the largest singular values instead ($\forall i: \sigma_i = \sigma_{\max}$)?

Comment: It does involve the largest singular values. But the largest is 1.

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\a{\alpha}  \def\s{\sigma}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\h{\odot} \def\t{\times}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\op{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\deriv#1#2{\frac{d #1}{d #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Given the Singular Value Decomposition of a matrix
$A\in\R{m\t n},\;\,r=\rank A$
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{k=\o}^r \s_k\,u_k\,v_k^T
 \qquad&{\rm where}\;\; \s_\o\gt\s_2\ge\ldots\ge\s_r\gt0 \\
\s_\o &= \|A\|_2 \quad&\{{\rm Spectral\ norm}\} \\
}$$
then from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3000223/357854) (and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602652/357854)) the gradient of the Spectral norm (wrt $A$) is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\s_\o}{A} &= u_\o v^T_\o \qiq d\s_\o = u_\o^T\,\c{dA}\:v_\o \\
}$$
Substituting $\,A=\bR{Y\a-X}\,$ yields the desired derivative
$$\eqalign{
d\s_\o &= u_\o^T\CLR{Yd\a}v_\o \qiq
\deriv{\s_\o}{\a} &= u_\o^TYv_\o \\
}$$