# Gradient of $A \mapsto \sigma_i (A)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, singular-values, non-smooth-analysis

Let $ A $  be an $m \times n$ matrix of rank $ k \le \min(m,n) $. Then we decompose $ A = USV^T $, where:

- $U$ is $m \times k$  is a **semi-orthogonal** matrix.
- $S$ is $k \times k$ **diagonal** matrix , of which its diagonal entries are called singular values
  of $ A $. we denote them by $ \sigma _i = S_{ii} $.
- $V$ is  $n \times k$ **semi-orthogonal** matrix.
- Definition: a **semi-orthogonal** matrix $ Q $ is a non-square matrix where $ Q^{T}Q=I $.

This is the singular value decomposition (SVD) of matrix $ A $. We define a function $ f_i: \mathbb R^{ m \times n} \to \mathbb R $ by $ f_i (A) = \sigma_i (A) $. I am interested in finding the gradient of $ f_i $ in order to practice matrix defferentiation.

---

I hope you can help me starting with the first steps. Here are the hints that I have been given in order to find the solution, and feel free to use them:

1. Use the product rule of differentials to calculate $ dA $ where A is considered as function of $ U $, $ S $  and $ V $.
2. The entries of the diagonal of anti-symmetric matrix are all zeros.
3. The Hadamard product of two matrices $ A,B $ of the same size , is denoted by $$ (A \circ B )_{ij} = A_{ij} \cdot B_{ij} $$
4. Use the cyclic property of the trace operator. That is:

   $$\mbox{Tr}(ABC) = \mbox{Tr}(CAB) = \mbox{Tr}(BCA)$$

   5. The trace of a scalar is a scalar. That is, given $ a \in \mathbb R $:

      $$ \mbox{Tr}(a) = a $$

I stuck right at the beginning, I found that the product rule is:

$$ dA = dUSV^{T} +  UdSV^{T}  +  USdV^{T}  $$

Also, I have tried to calculate $ A^{T}A $ as trying to find a useful manipulation where I can use it for the solution, and I got that it is equal to: $ VS^{T} SV^{T} $.
First of all, is this what they meant by the product rule? And, second, how do I continue from here?

Comment: Please, show the steps you have tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929434/339790

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2795443/339790

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks. it helps. but I still can't see how to find a function $f_i (a) =  \sigma_i  $ where $ i > 1 $. it seems that this norm works only for finding $ \sigma_1 $

Comment: I hope the tagging of the question is now settled; if there is further need for discussion or actions please inform me via a ping.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\{e_i\}$ denote the standard basis vectors. Then $q_i=Qe_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $Q$.

The definition of *semi-orthogonality* says that the columns of $Q$ are orthonormal, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
I &= Q^TQ \\
e_i^T(I)e_j &= e_i^T(Q^TQ)e_j \\
\delta_{ij} &= q_i^Tq_j \\
}$$
Multiply the SVD by the 
$i^{th}$ columns of $(U,V)$ to isolate the
$i^{th}$ singular value.
$$\eqalign{
A &= \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j u_j v_j^T \\
u_i^TAv_i &= \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j (u_i^Tu_j)(v_j^Tv_i) 
  = \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j\,\delta_{ij}^2 \;=\; \sigma_i \\
}$$
Rearrange this result with the help of the trace/Frobenius product
$\Big(A\!:\!B={\rm Tr}\!\left(A^TB\right)\Big)$

Then calculate the differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\sigma_i &= u_iv_i^T:A \\
d\sigma_i &= u_iv_i^T:dA \\ 
\frac{\partial\sigma_i}{\partial A} &= u_iv_i^T \\
}$$
Similarly, the singular vectors also vary with $A$.
$$\eqalign{
\sigma_i u_i &= Av_i \\
\sigma_i u_i &= \left(v_i^T\otimes I_m\right){\rm vec}(A) \\
\sigma_i\,du_i &= \left(v_i^T\otimes I_m\right){\rm vec}(dA) \\
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial{\rm vec}(A)} &= \frac{v_i^T\otimes I_m}{\sigma_i} \\
\\
\\
\sigma_i v_i^T &= u_i^TA \\
\sigma_i v_i &= \left(I_n\otimes u_i^T\right){\rm vec}(A) \\
\sigma_i\,dv_i &= \left(I_n\otimes u_i^T\right){\rm vec}(dA) \\
\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial{\rm vec}(A)} &= \frac{I_n\otimes u_i^T}{\sigma_i} \\
\\
}$$

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort solving this question. it really helped.

Comment: @greg , if $\sigma_i$ is a multiple eigenvalue, then, with probability $1$, it has no derivative (cf. my post below).

Answer (score 2):

Here we consider the eigenvalues of $B=A^TA$, a symmetric $\geq 0$ matrix, where $spectrum(B)=\sigma_1\geq \sigma_2,\cdots$. If the $(\sigma_i)$ are distinct, then they admit derivative locally and even globally wrt the parameters. More precisely,

let $t\in(a,b)\mapsto B(t)\in sym_n$ be a smooth function. If, for every t, the eigenvalues of $B(t)$ are simple, then there are smooth local parametrizations of the spectrum: $\sigma_1(t),\cdots,\sigma_n(t)$.

$(*)$ More generally, this property stands when the mutiplicity of the eigenvalues are locally constant and is valid even for the non-symmetric matrices.

This is no longer the case when the eigenvalues ​​may be multiple. There are (counter-examples due to Rellich -1955-) smooth functions $B(t)$ with multiple eigenvalues s.t. one eigenvalue is only Lipschitz-continuous (and not derivable) and the associated eigenvector is not even continuous!

Yet, when $B(t)$ is analytic, we can do better

$\textbf{Proposition.}$ Assume that $t\in\mathbb{R}\rightarrow B(t)\in sym_n$ is analytic. Then, there is a numbering of the eigenvalues $(\lambda_i)_{i\leq n}$ and an ordered basis of (unit length) eigenvectors (associated to the $(\lambda_i)$) which are globally analytically parametrizable (even if the eigenvalues present some mutiplicities -their paths cross-).

Note that the natural ordering of the eigenvalues is not necessarily met; for example

$B(t)=diag(t+2,2t+2)$; when $t$ goes through $0$, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ are exchanged. In particular, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ (when they are ordered) have no derivative. However, the eigenvalues-functions $\lambda_1=t+2,\lambda_2=2t+2$ have derivatives.

$\textbf{Remark 1}$. The above results stand only when $B$ depends on only one parameter $t$; if $B$ depends on $\geq 2$ parameters or if $B$ is only a normal matrix, then the results are much more complicated, cf. [4].

$\textbf{Remark 2}$. In general, $\sigma_i$ is Lipschitz and differentiable a.e.; when $\sigma_i(t_0)$ is a multiple eigenvalue, it has a derivative in $t_0$ if, as part of the above Proposition, there is $j$ s.t. $\sigma_i=\lambda_j$ (at least locally). Note that, in general, that does not work.

[1] Rellich:   https://archive.org/details/perturbationtheo00rell/mode/2up

[2] Kazdan:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.00785.pdf

[3] About the roots of a polynomial, Michor: http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/roots.pdf

[4] Rainer: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4475v2.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using some basic convex analysis, and no calculation using coordinates or the canonical basis. It is more useful to work with
$$f_r(A) = \sum_{i\le r} \sigma_i(A)$$ (sum of $r$ largest singular values).
Of course, to deduce the derivative of the $r$-th singular value from the following argument, one can use that $\sigma_r(A) = f_r(A)-f_{r-1}(A)$ which gives the derivative of $\sigma_r(A)$ when both $f_r,f_{r-1}$ are differentiable at $A$.

We will gain much by noting that $f_r$ is convex, which follows from

> $$f_r(A) = \sup_{M: \|M\|_{op}\le 1, rank(M)\le r} trace[A^TM].$$

Why is this supremum expression for $f_r(A)$ true? Writing the SVD $A=\sum_i u_i s_i v_i^T$, define $\tilde A = \sum_{i\le r} (s_i -s_r) u_i v_i^T$, so that
$$
trace[A^TM]
-
trace[\tilde A^TM]
= trace[(A-\tilde A)^T M]
\le r s_r
$$
because $(A-\tilde A)^T M$ has rank at most $r$  and operator norm
at most $s_r$.
Furthermore,
$
trace[\tilde A^TM]
\le
\sum_{i\le r}(s_i - s_r) u_i^T M v_i
\le
\sum_{i\le r}(s_i - s_r)
$
because $M$ has operator norm at most 1 and $\|u_i\|=\|v_i\|=1$.
This proves $trace[A^TM] \le \sum_{i\le r} s_i$ and we have equality
for $M=\sum_{i\le r} u_i v_i^T$.

---

Now that we have the supremum expression for $f_r(A)$, we know that $f_r$ is a convex function (because a function defined as the supremum of linear functions is always convex).

Next, we can use the fact that

> a convex function $f_r:R^k\to R$ is differentiable at $A$
> if and only if the subdifferential of $f_r$ at $A$ is a singleton, and in this case the gradient of $f_r$ is the unique element of the sub-differential.

(We do not prove this fact here, but any convex analysis book will give a proof).
Here the subdifferential $\partial f_r(A)$ is the set of all matrices $G$ of the same size as $A$ such that for any matrix $H$ of the same size as $A$,
$$
f_r(A+H) \ge f_r(A) + trace[H^TG].
$$
If there is a jump between the $r$-th and $r+1$-th singular value then
for $H= - t M$ for $M=\sum_{i\le r} u_i v_i^T$ we have
$$
f_r(A+H) = \sum_{i\le r} \sigma_i(A+H)
= \sum_{i\le r} (s_i -t)
$$
for all $t$ such that $s_r-t>s_{r+1}$. Then for $t$ small enough,
any matrix $G$ in the subdifferential of $f_r$ at $A$ satisfies
$$
\sum_{i\le r} (s_i - t)
\ge 
\sum_{i\le r} s_i
- t ~\text{trace}[M^TG]
$$
or $0 \ge r - \text{trace}[M^TG]$.
Applying
$f_r(A) + f_r(H) \ge f_r(A+H) \ge f_r(A) + trace[H^TG]$ to $H=G$ further gives
$f_r(G) \ge \|G\|_F^2$, or in terms of singular values,
$$
\sum_{i\le r}\sigma_i(G) \ge \sum_{i\ge 1} \sigma_i(G)^2.
$$
By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it follows that
$\|G\|_F^2 \le r$. Also, $\|M\|_F^2\le r$. Thus the inequlaity
$0 \ge r - trace[M^TG]$ implies $0\ge (\|G\|_F^2 + \|M\|_F^2 - trace[M^TG])=
\|G-M\|_F^2$ so that $M=\sum_{i\le r} u_i v_i^T$ is the unique
element in the subdifferential of $f_r$ at $A$.
By the above basic fact of convex analysis, it follows that the function $f_r$ is differentiable at $A$ whenever $\sigma_r(A)>\sigma_{r+1}(A)$, and that for $M=\sum_{i\le r}u_i v_i^T$ as above we have for any $H$
$$
f_r(A+H) = f_r(A) + trace[M^TH] + o(H).
$$

---

We can also prove that $f_r$ is not differentiable at $A$ if $\sigma_r(A)=\sigma_{r+1}(A)$. Indeed, in this case the subdifferential contains both
$$
M = \sum_{i\le r} u_i v_i^T$ 
\text{ and }
M' = \sum_{i\le r-1} u_i v_i^T + u_{r+1} v_{r+1}^T.
$$
By the characterization of differentiability for convex functions, the subdifferential at $A$ is non-unique and the function $f_r$ not differentiable at $A$.