# Derivative of a matrix function that applies on the singular values

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, svd

Let $F(A)$ be a matrix-valued function, operating on real-valued matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m, n}$ that applies a scalar function $f(\lambda)$ on the singular values of $A$. That is, suppose $A$ has the following singular value decomposition:
$$
A = U \Sigma V^\top,
$$
with $U, V$ being orthogonal and $\Sigma$ being diagonal matrices, then
$$
B = F(A) = U F(\Sigma) V^\top,
$$
where $F(\Sigma)$ is computed by applying $f$ entry-wise on the diagonal elements of $\Sigma$. Let $g$ be a scalar-valued function that depends on the matrix $B$.

**Question:** How do we find $\dfrac{\partial g(B)}{\partial A}$? In this question,  $\dfrac{\partial g(B)}{\partial A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,n}$ is a matrix whose $(i,j)-$entry contains the value  $\dfrac{\partial g(B)}{\partial A_{i,j}}$. Also, I'm looking for (if there is any) a closed-form expression for this, and not just a procedure to compute the partial derivatives.

Comment: Perhaps [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351) can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\b{\beta}\def\g{\gamma}
\def\s{\sigma}\def\S{\Sigma}\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\l{\lambda}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\operatorname{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\bx{\boxtimes}
$Assume that the SVD decomposition has distinct
singular values $\{\s_k\}$
$$\eqalign{
A &= USV^T
  = \sum_{k=1}^r \s_k u_kv_k^T \\
A &\in\bbR{m\times n} \qquad 
U \in\bbR{m\times r},\;
S \in\bbR{r\times r},\;
V \in\bbR{n\times r} \\
r &= \rank{A} \\
}$$Let's rename the function $(f,g)\to(\b,\g),\,$ so that we can write the mnemonic equations
$$\eqalign{
B &= \b(A) = U\b(S)V^T
 \quad &\{{\rm matrix\;function}\} \\
\g &= \g(B)
 \quad &\{{\rm scalar\;function}\} \\
}$$
and for typing convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
s &= \diag S
 \quad &\{{\rm vector\;of\;singular\;values}\} \\
p &= \b(s)
 \qquad &\{{\rm function\;applied\;elementwise}\} \\
q &= \b'(s)
 \qquad &\{{\rm derivative\;applied\;elementwise}\} \\
P &= \b(S) \,= \Diag p \;& \\
Q &= \b'(S)\!= \Diag q \\
\\
u_k &= U\e_k \\
v_k &= V\e_k 
 \quad &\{\e_k\,{\rm are\;the\;standard\;basis\;vectors}\} \\
G &= \grad{\g}{B}
 \quad &\{{\rm gradient\;of\;}\g\;{\rm is\;\c{known}}\} \\
g &= \vecc G \\
b &= \vecc B \\
K &= {V\bx U}
 \quad &\{{\rm Khatri-Rao\;product}\} \\
\l_k &= g^TKQ\e_k \\
}$$
Use the [column-wise Khatri-Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatri%E2%80%93Rao_product#Column-wise_Kronecker_product) product to expand $\vecc B$
and calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
B &= U\,\Diag{p}\;V^T \\
b &= Kp \\
db &= K\,\c{dp} \\
  &= K\c{Q\,ds} \\
}$$
Substitute this into the differential of $\g$
$$\eqalign{
d\g
 &= G:dB \\
 &= g^T\c{db} \\
 &= g^T\c{KQ\,ds} \\
}$$
This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351/) provides a formula for the gradient of the singular values
$$\eqalign{
d\s_k &= u_k v_k^T:dA \\
s &= \sum_{k=1}^r \e_k\star \s_k \\
ds &= \sum_{k=1}^r \e_k\star d\s_k
  \;=\; \LR{\sum_{k=1}^r \e_k\star u_k v_k^T}:dA \\
}$$
which yields the desired gradient
$$\eqalign{
d\g
 &= g^TKQ\,ds \\
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=1}^r\CLR{g^TKQ\e_k}\LR{u_k v_k^T}}:dA \\
 &= \LR{\sum_{k=1}^r\c{\l_k} u_k v_k^T}:dA \\
\grad{\g}{A}
  &= \sum_{k=1}^r {\l_k u_k v_k^T}
 \;=\; ULV^T \\
}$$
where $L$ is a matrix whose diagonal elements are the $\l_k$ values.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. May I clarify when you wrote $d\gamma = G : dB$, what does the colon mean? I'm not very familiar with differentials so I would appreciate it if you could point me to some references that explain the notations.

Comment: @LamChiThanh The colon denotes the Frobenius inner product for matrices $$A:B\;=\;{\rm trace}\!\left(A^TB\right)$$ In engineering disciplines it is often called the _double-dot_ product.

Comment: As for reference material, the standard text is probably
Magnus and Neudecker's _Matrix Differential Calculus_ although personally I prefer
Hjorungnes's _Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives_

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Just one more clarifying question, what is the $\star$ in $\epsilon_k \star u_k v_k^\top$? Does that refer to matrix multiplication?

Comment: @LamChiThanh That is my own non-standard notation for a [dyadic](https://web.stanford.edu/class/me331b/documents/VectorBasisIndependent.pdf) product. Older engineering texts often use the notation $(a\otimes b)$, but these days that symbol is reserved for the Kronecker product. In continuum mechanics, simple juxtaposition is used $($i.e. $\,ab)$, but that notation is too easily confused with the standard matrix product. So the quantity $(\varepsilon\star uv^T = \varepsilon\star u\star v)$ actually represents a _triadic_ or third-order tensor.

Answer (score 1):

To go one step further the excellent answer from Greg, one can remark that $\lambda_k$ can be simplfied a bit.

\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_k
&=&
\mathbf{g}^T \mathbf{K} \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{e}_k \\
&=&
q_k \mathbf{g}^T \mathbf{K} \mathbf{e}_k \\
&=&
q_k \mathbf{g}^T \mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{u}_k \mathbf{v}_k^T) \\
&=&
\mathbf{G}: q_k\mathbf{u}_k \mathbf{v}_k^T
\end{eqnarray}