# What is the second derivative of the spectral norm of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, hessian-matrix, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis, spectral-norm

It is well known that the derivative of a matrix $A$'s $2$-norm with respect to $A$ is $$\frac{\partial \sigma_{\max}(A)}{\partial A}=u_1v_1^T,$$ where $u_1,v_1$ are the first column/row in the SVD matrices. However, I want to know if we have an explicit formula for the second derivative of $\sigma_{\max}(A)$?

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric, then $u_1 = v_1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\op{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\Hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=\o}^{\rank A}}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\k{\otimes}
\def\Im{I_m}
\def\In{I_n}
$Summarizing the results from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602652/357854)
$$\eqalign{
A &= \Sk \s_k\, u_k\, v_k^T,\quad 
&A \in\R{m\times n},\;\;u_k\in\R m,\;\;v_k\in\R n \\
a &= \vc A,\qquad
&\grad{\s_k}{A} = u_k\,v_k^T
\\
\grad{u_k}{a} &= \fracLR{v_k\k\Im}{\s_k}^T,\quad 
&\grad{v_k}{a} = \fracLR{\In\k u_k}{\s_k}^T \\
}$$
Let's drop the subscripts and implicitly
take $k=\o$ in the following calculations.
$$\eqalign{
G &= \grad{\s}{A} \,=\, uv^T
 \qquad \qquad \{{\rm gradient\;matrix}\} \\
dG &= du\:v^T + u\:dv^T \\
dg &= \c{\vc{dG}} \;\doteq\; \LR{v\k\Im} du + \LR{\In\k u} dv \\
dg &= \fracLR{\LR{v\k\Im}\LR{v\k\Im}^T}{\s} da
  + \fracLR{\LR{\In\k u}\LR{\In\k u}^T}{\s} da \\
\grad{g}{a}
 &= \frac{\LR{v\k\Im}\LR{v\k\Im}^T \;+\; \LR{\In\k u}\LR{\In\k u}^T}{\s} \\
}$$
The last line is the requested Hessian (i.e. the second derivative)
$$\eqalign{
\Hess{\s}a \,=\, \grad{g}{a} \\
}$$
expressed using [vectorized](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) matrices.
Without vectorization, it's a $4^{th}$ order tensor.