# Derivative of 2-norm of a matrix.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, condition-number

I have a function:
$$f(A)=cond(AB)=\left \|{AB}\right \|_2 \left \| {(AB)^{-1}} \right \|_2  $$
We know that:
$$\left \| X \right \|_2= \sqrt{\lambda_{max}(X^TX)}$$
So:
$$f(A)=\sqrt{\dfrac {\lambda_{max}((AB)^T(AB))} {\lambda_{min}((AB)^T(AB))}}$$
How should I take the derivation of $f(A)$ with respect to matrix $A$ ?
$$\dfrac {df(A)} {dA}$$

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\k{\kappa}
\def\s{\sigma}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\so{\s_\o} \def\sr{\s_r}
\def\uo{u_\o}  \def\ur{u_r}
\def\vo{v_\o}  \def\vr{v_r}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\rank#1{\op{rank}\LR{#1}}
\def\cond#1{\op{cond}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$Let $C=AB$ and calculate its SVD and condition number
$$\eqalign{
r &= \rank C,\qquad
C &= \sum_{i=\o}^r \s_i u_i v_i^T \qquad
\k = \cond C &= \fracLR{\so}{\sr} \\
}$$
From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3602652/357854), the gradient of the $k^{th}$
singular value is
$\;{\large\grad{\s_k}C} = u_kv_k^T\;\;$
(if it exists)

The gradient of the condition number (assuming it's finite)
is therefore
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\k}C
 &= \fracLR{\sr\uo\vo^T-\so\ur\vr^T}{\sr^2} 
 &= \frac{\uo\vo^T-\k\ur\vr^T}{\sr} 
\\
}$$
Rearrange this to recover the gradient wrt $A$
$$\eqalign{
d\k
 &= \fracLR{\uo\vo^T-\k\ur\vr^T}{\sr}:\c{dC} \\
 &= \fracLR{\uo\vo^T-\k\ur\vr^T}{\sr}:\CLR{dA\:B} \\
 &= \fracLR{\uo\vo^T-\k\ur\vr^T}{\sr} B^T:dA \\
\grad{\k}A
 &= \fracLR{\uo\vo^T-\k\ur\vr^T}{\sr}B^T \\
}$$

---

In the above derivation, a colon denotes the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
M:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{M^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
M:B &= B:M \;=\; B^T:M^T \\
\LR{XY}:B &= X:\LR{BY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TB} \\
}$$