# Gradient of the spectral norm of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, matrix-calculus, singular-values, spectral-norm

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$ and

$$\|X\|_2 = \sigma_{\max}(X) = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( X^T X \right)}$$

How can I compute $\nabla_X \|AX\|_2$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{c \times a}$ is some known matrix?

Comment: Why do you need the gradient?

Comment: I want to find X minimizing $||AX||_2$, and I would like to find the optimum by using gradient descent. The problem could be solved with semidefinite programming, however I need to consider gradient descent.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701062.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a matrix and its SVD 
$$Y = \sum_{k=1}^r\sigma_ku_kv_k$$
and let $\,\phi=\|Y\|=\sigma_1\,$ be the spectral norm $($assuming that the singular values are ordered such that $\sigma_1>\sigma_2>\sigma_3>\ldots>\sigma_r>0\,)$

The gradient of the norm is
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial Y} = u_1v_1^T$$

Write the differential in terms of this gradient and perform a change of variables $Y=AX$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi
  &= u_1v_1^T:dY \cr
  &= u_1v_1^T:A\,dX \cr
  &= A^Tu_1v_1^T:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= A^Tu_1v_1^T \cr
}$$
to obtain the desired gradient.

A colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB),\,$
in some of the steps above.

If the first few singular values are identical, $($e.g. $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma_3)$, then the result changes slightly
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= \sum_{k=1}^3A^Tu_kv_k^T \cr
}$$

Comment: Could you please expand on why $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial Y}=u_1 v_1^T$?

Comment: I'll refer you to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929434/357854) for the details.

Comment: @greg , $||AX||_2$ admits a derivative essentially when the multiplicity of the largest singular eigenvalue is locally constant. Otherwise, cf. the case when $U=diag(t+2,2t+2)$ and $t0=0$.

Comment: @greg , if $\sigma_1=\sigma_2=\sigma_3$ in a point, then, in general, $\sigma_1$ has no derivative. cf. my post and my comment  in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351/gradient-of-a-mapsto-sigma-i-a/3630189#3630189