# Deriving a Subgradient for l2 norm composition over affine function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I need to explain how to compute a subgradient at a given point x (not necessarily deriving it but just explain how it can be derived) for the following function:
$$\newcommand{\defeq}{\mathrel{:\mkern-0.25mu=}}$$
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = \vert\vert \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \mathbf{A_{i}} -\mathbf{B} \vert \vert _{2}$$
where $\forall i \mathbf{A_{i}}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times q}$ and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$
My direction so far was to look at the definition of 2 norm of matrices $\vert\vert  \mathbf{B} \vert \vert _{2} = \sqrt{\lambda_{max} (\mathbf{B}^{*}\mathbf{B}})$ and trying to use the fact that $A(\mathbf{x})^{*}A(\mathbf{x})$ is a convex function of $\mathbf{x}$ for $A(\mathbf{x}) \defeq  \Sigma_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \mathbf{A_{i}} -\mathbf{B} $ and therefor $\lambda_{max} (A(\mathbf{x})^{*}A(\mathbf{x}))$ has a subgradient (you can see that by the fact that $\lambda_{max}(A(\mathbf{x})^{*}A(\mathbf{x})) = max_{ \vert \vert \mathbf{u} \vert \vert =1} \mathbf{u}^{*} (\mathbf{A(\mathbf{x})^{*}A(\mathbf{x}))} \mathbf{u} $ is a maximum over convex functions of x).
The problem is that from there I am stuck, I want to use some sort of chain rule but $\sqrt{x}$ is not a convex function...
I am new to the subject of subgradients and I have been stuck on this exercise for a few days already, any help would be most welcomed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Something is wrong with the dimensions. Also a multiplication of a Matrix and Vector yields a vector so subtracting a Matrix doesn't make sense.

Comment: $x_{i}$ are scalars and corresponding to the elements of the vector, scalar multiplication by a matrix remain a matrix

Comment: I think you just edit the question and write: The Sub Gradient of $ {L}_{2} $ Induced Matrix Norm. Then the question should be: What's the Sub Gradient with respect to $ X $ of $  {\left\| A X - B \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ where $  {\left\| Y \right\|}_{2}^{2} =  {\lambda}_{max} \left( {Y}^{^T} T \right) $.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795443.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351.

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701062.