# Calculate gradient of the spectral norm analytically

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, spectral-norm

Given a tall matrix $F \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times n}$, where $m > n$, and a non-symmetric matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$, consider the spectral norm

$$ \begin{aligned} \| A - F^* \operatorname{diag}(b) F \|_2 &= \sigma_{\max} \left( A - F^* \operatorname{diag}(b) F \right) \\ &= \sqrt{\lambda_{\max} \left( (A-F^*\operatorname{diag}(b)F)^* (A-F^*\operatorname{diag}(b)F ) \right),} \end{aligned} $$

How do I compute analytically $\nabla_b \|A-F^*\operatorname{diag}(b)F\|_2$, where $b \in \mathbb{C}^{m \times 1}$ is some vector and {$*$} is a sign for conjugate transpose?

I need gradient because I want to find $b$ by minimizing $\|A-F^*\operatorname{diag}(b)F\|_2$ as I would like to find the optimum by using gradient descent. Is it possible?

Comment: If you only care about result and your problem is not too large, use a monte-carlo based method. They don't converge as fast, but they don't require you to know the gradient. See, for example the [metropolis-hastings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm) algorithm. The logic is to compute the value at a random point not too far from the current point, and move to it with a certain probability, that is larger if your result is better than the one before

Comment: @AleksejsFomins  Is there an analytic way to do this?

Comment: To do what? Metropolis-Hastings - no, it is a numerical technique: you plug in a metric you want to minimize, you get back a vector that minimizes it. Gradient Descent that you have expressed the intent of using also is not analytical - it is a numeric technique for finding minimum or maximum. It is a little faster than MH, but it only works if your problem has only 1 maximum/minimum. Perhaps you are asking if it is possible to find the gradient you seek analytically - I don't know. What I try to say is that maybe you don't even need it

Answer (score 2):

Let's use $\big\{F^T,\,F^C,\,F^H=(F^C)^T\big\}\,$ to denote the $\big\{$Transpose, Complex, Hermitian$\big\}$ conjugates of $F$, respectively.

Let's also use the Frobenius product (:) notation instead of the Trace function, i.e.
$$A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
[**NB:**  The use of $A^T$ (rather than $A^H$) on the RHS is deliberate.]

Define the variables
$$\eqalign{
B &= {\rm Diag}(b) \cr
X &= F^HBF-A \cr
}$$
Given the SVD of $X$ 
$$\eqalign{
X &= USV^H \cr
U &= \big[\,u_1\,u_2 \ldots u_n\,\big],\,&u_k&\in{\mathbb C}^{m\times 1} \cr
S &= {\rm Diag}(\sigma_k),&S&\in{\mathbb R}^{n\times n} \cr
V &= \big[\,v_1\,v_2 \ldots v_n\,\big],&v_k&\in{\mathbb C}^{n\times 1} \cr
}$$
where the $\sigma_k$ are ordered such that $\,\,\sigma_1>\sigma_2\ge\ldots\ge\sigma_n\ge 0$

The gradient of the spectral norm $\phi = \|X\|_2$ can be written as 
$$G = \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} = (u_1v_1^H)^C = u_1^Cv_1^T$$
To find the gradient wrt the vector $b$, write the differential and perform a change of variables.
$$\eqalign{
 d\phi &= G:dX \cr
 &= G:F^H\,dB\,F \cr
 &= F^C GF^T:dB \cr
 &= F^C GF^T:{\rm Diag}(db) \cr
 &= {\rm diag}\big(F^CGF^T\big):db \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial b}
 &= {\rm diag}\big(F^CGF^T\big) \cr
 &= {\rm diag}\big((Fu_1)^C(Fv_1)^T\big) \cr
}$$

Comment: Nice proof. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929434/derivative-of-spectral-norm-of-symmetric-matrix) post useful in understanding one of the steps better

Comment: @AleksejsFomins Looking at that post (especially python_enthusiast's answer) made me realize that I had mistakenly calculated the complex conjugate of $G$, which I have now corrected. Thanks.