# Gradient of spectral norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, matrix-norms, singular-values, spectral-norm

I am looking for a reference for the following result:

---

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$ real matrix. Let $\sigma(A)$ be the spectral norm of $A$. If the largest singular value of $A$ is unique, then

$$ \nabla_A \sigma (A) = \mathbf{u} \mathbf{v}^{\top}, $$

where $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ denote the first left- and right-singular (column) vectors, respectively.

---

I am aware of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929434/derivative-of-spectral-norm-of-symmetric-matrix), and am not asking about the proof. Could you please let me know references (e.g., textbooks) about this result? Thank you.

Comment: The answers provided in the linked question seem quite good. A textbook will most likely simply reproduce one of them. What's the point?  The result is also subject to direct _numerical_ verification, if that boosts your confidence.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thank for editing my question. You can find this result, for example, at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/929434/derivative-of-spectral-norm-of-symmetric-matrix

Comment: @greg Yes, I like the answers provided in the linked question, but I just wanted to know the textbook treatment.

Comment: @greg Could you please tell me a textbook that reproduces one of the proofs (in the link)? I need a published reference. Thank you.

Comment: Try Harville's  _Matrix Algebra from a Statistician's Perspective_   in the chapter on eigenvalues near the end of the book.