# On the gradient of spectral norm of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, spectral-norm

Let $\| A \|_2 := \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}$. As part of the gradient of a regularized loss function (for machine learning), I need the gradient $\nabla_A \| A \|_2^2$, which, using the chain rule, expands to $2 \| A \|_2 \nabla_A \| A \|_2$. How can I find $\nabla_A \| A \|_2$?

I start with $\|A\|_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^TA)}$, then get

$$\nabla_A \| A \|_2 = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\lambda_{\max}(A^T A)}} \nabla_A \left(\lambda_{\max} \left( A^T A \right) \right)$$

but after that I have no idea how to find $\nabla_A \left(\lambda_{\max} \left( A^T A \right) \right)$.

edit: would I just take the derivative of $A$ (call it $A'$), and take $\lambda_{\max}(A'^TA')$?

Comment: you could use the singular value decomposition. for this approach take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601351/gradient-of-a-mapsto-sigma-i-a

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929434/339790)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the SVD of
$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{U}\mathbf{\Sigma}\mathbf{V}^T$.
It follows that
$\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{V}\mathbf{\Sigma}^2\mathbf{V}$.

The matrix norm is thus
related to the maximum singular value of
$\mathbf{A}$.
Let $s_1$ be such value with the corresponding
left and right singular vectors
$\mathbf{u}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_1$.

$$
\| \mathbf{A} \|_2 
= \sigma_1(\mathbf{A})
= \sqrt{\lambda_1
\left( \mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{A} \right)}
$$

We know that
$$d\sigma_1 = \mathbf{u}_1 \mathbf{v}_1^T : d\mathbf{A}$$

It follows that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}
\| \mathbf{A} \|_2^2
=
2 \sigma_1  \mathbf{u}_1 \mathbf{v}_1^T
$$