# Expanding the derivative of a singular value using chain rule

Tags: matrix-calculus, chain-rule

Say I have a positive definite matrix $M(\sigma)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ whose elements are functions of some variable $\sigma \in \mathbb R$. I am wondering how I can expand $\frac{d \eta_i}{d \sigma}$ using the chain rule, where $\eta_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of $M(\sigma)$.

For example, I imagine it should be something like

$$ \frac{d \eta_i}{d \sigma} = \frac{d \eta_i}{d M} \frac{d M}{d \sigma} $$

but it doesn't seem to make sense if I try to think what the shapes of the vectors $\frac{d \eta_i}{d M}$ and $\frac{d M}{d \sigma}$ should be. So I think maybe

$$ \frac{d \eta_i}{d \sigma} =\sum_{kj} \frac{d \eta_i}{d M_{kj}} \frac{d M_{kj}}{d \sigma} $$

makes more sense, but I can't explain why. Also even if this expansion is correct, how can one compute $\frac{d \eta_i}{d M_{kj}} $ to begin with?

Comment: I've been holding my tongue because I don't want to give a bad answer -- but I suspect working through the SVD may be useful? Writing $M=UDV^*$, your $\eta_i$ is $D_{11}$, and it's just possible that you can turn $M$'s dependence on $\sigma$ into a dependence of $U$ and $V$ on $\sigma$ in a way that lets you use their geometric interpretation in the chain rule. Not (at all) my area though, so confirm with someone else before following on this path. Good luck, very interesting question!

Comment: Related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3601351)

Comment: Another [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/929434)